# Vb.Net's with keyword in java?

Tags: c#, java, .net, vb.net, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WITH statement in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494800/with-statement-in-java)

Hi all, does anyone know if there is the [`With Keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336816.aspx) in Java?

Or something similar..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something similar with chained calls.

e.g.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hello")
  .append("World")
  .reverse();
```

This is a common pattern with builder objects. However, it is not Java language feature.

---

From the Guava MapMake example

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
   .concurrencyLevel(4)
   .weakKeys()
   .maximumSize(10000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .makeComputingMap(
       new Function<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph apply(Key key) {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 5):

Luckily, there's no such thing in Java.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't believe there is such a construct in java, or anything similar, and for good reason :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function FunctionProxy( sourceCode ){


return(
Function(
"with (this){" +
"return(" +
"(function(){" + sourceCode + "})()" +
");" +
"};"
)
)};
```

with keywrd is used in c# and javascript, not in java