# Equivalent of VBA With statement in Java

Tags: java, vba, with-statement

I am currently making my method call in the following way:

```
InstrumentsInfo instrumentsInfo = new InstrumentsInfo();
String shortInstruName = "EURUSD"

TrackInstruments trackInstruments = new TrackInstruments(instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentID(shortInstruName), instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentTickSize(shortInstruName), instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentName(shortInstruName));
```

In VBA I would do something like this

```
With instrumentsInfo
 TrackInstruments(.getInstrumentID(shortInstruName), .getInstrumentTickSize(shortInstruName), .getInstrumentName(shortInstruName));
```

So my question is, is there a way to avoid repeating "instrumentsInfo" in the method call in Java?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494800/with-statement-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word no although you may want to consider changing

```
TrackInstruments trackInstruments = new TrackInstruments(instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentID(shortInstruName), instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentTickSize(shortInstruName), instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentName(shortInstruName));
```

to

```
TrackInstruments trackInstruments = new TrackInstruments(instrumentsInfo);
```

and then have the constructor take the parameters it needs.

Or perhaps use the [builder](http://rwhansen.blogspot.co.uk/2007/07/theres-builder-pattern-that-joshua.html) pattern if you need a lot of parameters.

Or indeed ask yourself why you are constructing `InstrumentsInfo`  outside the `TrackInstruments` when the latter seems to rely on it so heavily. (Without fully understanding your objects that is)

Comment: a builder sounds like a good idea as I would keep visibilty on what params I pass in my method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a constructor in TrackInstruments that accepts the object type InstrumentsInfo

```
TrackInstruments trackInstruments = new TrackInstruments(instrumentsInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no `With` syntax in Java as such. To avoid repeating "instrumentsInfo", you could, however, just create a constructor which takes the type:

```
TrackInstruments trackInstruments = new TrackInstruments(instrumentsInfo);
```

This design, however, leads to the `TrackInstruments` knowing about an `InstrumentsInfo` which does not promote loose coupling between objects, so you could use:

```
Integer instrumentID = instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentID(shortInstruName);
Integer instrumentTickSize = instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentTickSize(shortInstruName);
String instrumentName = instrumentsInfo.getInstrumentName(shortInstruName);

TrackInstruments trackInstruments = new TrackInstruments(instrumentID, instrumentTickSize, instrumentName);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about doing your suggestion but passing instrumentInfo I would loose visibility on what params I use in my method call, i.e name, ID etc.