# Is there any Equivalent Keyword in android like "with" in VB6

Tags: android, android-listview, vb6

I am new to android and I've been trying to create a ListView example application, in which I've added items to Arraylist....

```
list.add("Item1");
list.add("Item2");
list.add("Item3");
.......
```

Is there any way in android to avoid typing "List" every Time....?
I know there is something ,But I couldn't find out what the keyword is..

in VB I could write

```
with list
.add("Item1");
.add("Item2");
```

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there isn't.. What you can do is use [`Arrays.asList(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) which you can pass any number of arguments to and you'll get a list with these items back

Comment: I thought There will some keyword that I can Use...:( Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no Java equivalent of the Visual Basic with statement.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494800/with-statement-in-java).