# What is the java equivalent of VBA's "With" statement

Tags: java, vba

In VB / VBA you can do something like this:

```
With person
    .Name = "John"
    .Age = 32
End With
```

But in java I can't figure out how or if that functionality exists. Everything I see seems to just repeat the object references, like this:

```
person.setName("John");
person.setAge("32");
```

If it doesn't exists, is there at least some methodology to cut down on the repetition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494800/with-statement-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If it doesn't exists, is there at least some methodology to cut down on the repetition?

Nope, not really - not unless you control the type.

If you *do* control the type, you can make the `set` methods return `this`, allowing you to chain the method calls. This is often useful for *builder* types:

```
Person person = Person.newBuilder().setName("John").setAge(32).build();
```

(You can just make your types mutable rather than separating builder types from immutable non-builder types, but I'm just a fan of immutability...)